# MySQL CAST and LIKE in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I want to write following query in MySQL and keep getting errors. I have no idea what's wrong, everything seems fine by me.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    client
WHERE
    id IN (
        SELECT 
            client_id 
        FROM 
            url 
        WHERE 
            ',1,2,' LIKE '%,' + CAST(url_type_id AS CHAR(50)) + ',%'
        )
```

It must have got something to do with the "'%,' + " part, but I honestly don't get it

Comment: Can you share the table structure and error you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [CONCAT()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) to join 2 strings not "+", here is the query which you looking for

```
SELECT *
FROM client
WHERE id IN ( SELECT client_id 
        FROM url 
        WHERE ',1,2,' LIKE CONCAT('%,', CAST(url_type_id AS CHAR(50)), ',%') 
)
```

Comment: aha this was the problem indeed. I thought I could use "+" as I would in SQL 2008